# API not returning updated data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-api

I have this weird problem. It works fine on my local machine. But the problem happens when I upload this project on the live server (in a sub-domain for testing purposes). [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Jamiul-Bari/LaravelAPITest.git)

The project has one Model (other than User), "Post"

The project has one route and one API endpoint. Initially, I should get the same results from both the web route and API endpoint. The problem is when I delete a post from the web, the API result still shows that deleted post. The API returns updated results after 20-30 minutes.

Very strange issue.

If anyone knows anything about such an issue, please help me out.

I am using Livewire

App\Http\Livewire\Posts.php

```
public function render()
{
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw("
        posts.id AS id,
        posts.title AS title,
        posts.category AS category,
        posts.author AS author
    "))
    ->orderBy('posts.category')
    ->get();

    $data = [
        'posts' => $posts
    ];

    return view('livewire.posts', $data);
}
```

api.php

```
Route::get('posts', function() {
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw("
        posts.id AS id,
        posts.title AS title,
        posts.category AS category,
        posts.author AS author
    "))
    ->orderBy('posts.category');

return response()->json($posts->get(), 200);
```

});

Comment: When you delete the post from the web UI have you checked the DB to make sure it had been deleted?

Comment: @LukeRayner Yes, I've just checked it after you suggested it, and it indeed was deleted. I used a database seeder to create 200 posts. Now, there are 198 records (2 were deleted).

Comment: And your API is still returning 200 records? If so must be a caching issue trying running php artisan route:cache after deleting one and see if the API now returns the correct amount

Comment: @LukeRayner tried route:cache (after removing closures), but same result

Comment: Are you sure the correct record is deleted? maybe a wrong ID number is sent to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it was my fault. I did try

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

And it did not work since there was a caching configuration in Nginx.

You know, when you are a noob at server management and end up using a nice and ready solution like [myvestacp](https://myvestacp.com), you may end up making silly mistakes like this.

The way myvestacp is configured, it utilizes a combination of Apache and Nginx (as proxy). Without knowing the outcome, I had set the Nginx proxy as "caching" instead of "hosting-public". This is why the API result would get cached and only update after some time.

I did not face any issues so far because I did not use API before.

But thank you anyway for your time and effort.